# VBA Excel, Compare strings from cells

Tags: vba, excel, range

i have problem with my VBA app. At the ssheet1 i have names in format Curry,Steph and every name is having an id. At changedNames i have the same names but in other format which is Steph Curry again with optional id which is the same as Curry,Steph. How can i make the names that i enter like Curry,Steph to change to the other type Steph Curry and to be with the same id. Also when i do the removeDuplicates method, its removing a digit from the id but the thing i want its to delete the row. Thanks in advance!

```
 Sub GenerateNames()

 Dim ssheet1 As Worksheet
 Dim rngen As Worksheet
 Dim rnsheet As Worksheet
 Dim changedNames As Worksheet

 Set ssheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
 Set rngen = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RnGen")
 Set rnsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RandomNames")
 Set changedNames = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ChangedNames")

 rngen.Range("A3:A70").Copy rnsheet.Range("A3:A70")
 ssheet1.Range("B3:B70").Copy rnsheet.Range("B3:B70")

  For b = 1 To 70
        For c = b + 1 To 70
            If Cells(b, 2).Value = Cells(c, 2).Value Then
                Cells.RemoveDuplicates

            End If
        Next c
    Next b
End Sub
```

Comment: are the IDs in the same cells or in a cell next to them?

Comment: The A columns are the names and the B columns are the Id's, so they are in the cells next to them

Comment: Welcome to [so]!  here are a lot of similar questions (with answers), have you checked?-- but it's impossible to tell exactly what will solve your issue without knowing more about your data and what you're trying to do.  For example, will a name only ever have one "space" or could there sometimes be names like "Mary Jane Smith".  Will names always be spelled exactly the same between both lists, or could they be abbreviated, etc, (Bob vs Bobby vs Robert vs Rob vs R.) What does the ID look like?  What do you mean "remove a digit"?  Descriptions are easier to understand if they have examples.

Comment: The names always will have only one "space" if there is a name like Mary Jane Smith it will be Mary-Jane Smith, the names will be spelled exactly the same and the id's are like 12345 but when i run the code with RemoveDuplicates if there are two users with the same ID's the first one stays with 12345 but the second become with 1234 for example.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

Not tested:

```
  For b = 70 To 1 step (-1)
        For c = 70 to b + 1 step (-1)
            If Cells(b, 2).Value = Cells(c, 2).Value Then
                Cells(c,2).row.delete
            End If
        Next c
    Next b
```